# My test for user input matches correctly for one input, but not for others

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
while True:
    game = input("Would you like to play: Guess the integer(i) or true/false(t). **Case Senestive** ")
    if not name.isalpha():
        print (name, "Enter the correct values")
        continue
    if not game == "i" or game == "t" or game=="integer" or game=="true/false":
        print ("Enter i, integer or true/false, t")
        continue
    else:
        break
```

I want to make it if they don't type `'i'` or `'integer'` it goes to the part saying `not game == "i" or game=="integer"`. Whenever I enter `i` it works, but not when I enter `integer`.

Comment: Please put the code into your question as text. You can highlight it and hit Ctrl-k to keep the format nice.

Comment: I have edited the original post, and included the code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to put parentheses around your `or` conditions:

```
if not (game == "i" or game == "t" or game=="integer" or game=="true/false"):
```

otherwise Python sees this as `(not game == "i") or ...`.

You'd be better off using `not in` on a set:

```
if game not in {"i", "t", "integer", "true/false"}:
```

Not only is this shorter, it is also faster; only one check constant-time check is made rather than separate `==` tests for each string.